# Trying to get a string from another class

Tags: android, class

In my login class I get the users name.  Then in my report class I try to retrieve that name.  I have used breakpoints when I enter the users name in login the string appears correct.  However, when I try to access it from the report class the function from login then returns a null string.  I have looked around on stack and used google and am pretty sure I am following what I am supposed to do but it is not working.

Here is some code from login.  I can show more code if needed, but when I use breakpoints in login, the dName is always the correct name, and so is driversName.  But when I come back to returnName from report, driversName is then a null string.  I have declared driversName as a global and not local variable in my class.

```
private void getDriversName(String dName)
{
    driversName=dName;
}

public String returnName()
{
    return driversName;

}
```

Here is the code from report.  Once again I can add more id needed.  Also I imported login correctly. I used breakpoints and when I used the step in, it took me to login. name is coming back null.

```
   LogIn login;
   login=new LogIn();
   String name= login.returnName();
   driver.setText(name);
```

UPDATE:  I figured it out I needed to add static.

Comment: When is the username obtained by the login screen?  It looks like you are trying to get something from a new instance of LogIn that might not actually be there (or it is in a different instance of LogIn).  Some more code would probably help.

Comment: Are these in separate activities (login & report)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you calling **getDriversName** function before calling login.returnName(); as from your code it is visible that driversName will have value right after getDriversName function call.

Further you can implement other approach for login and other tasks i.e. keep a common class which maintains all such sessions. You can set values once you login and then get them any where in your whole project. Like

```
Common.getUserName()
{
    return USERNAME;
}
```

and call this function after login success.

```
Common.setUserName(String name)
{

this.USERNAME= name;

}
```

Hope this will help.

Answer (score 1):

You're creating a new `LogIn()` object then immediately checking the return name. Unless the name is set in the constructor somehow, it will always return the default value.

Comment: When I comment the new Login() out I get a null pointer exception.

Answer (score 1):

Well, `login=new LogIn();` means you want Java to create a new instance of the `LogIn` class. Whenever a new instance is created, it has no knowledge of any old instances that may have been lying around. What you probably want to do is hold on to the username (like below, for example) and ask for that when you need it in the "report" class.

Something as simple as this would do the trick:

```
public class UserContext {
    public static String USERNAME;
    public static void setUsername(String name) {
        USERNAME = name;
    }
}
```

In your LogIn class, verify the credentials then call `UserContext.setUsername(...)` with the authenticated username, then in your report class, you can use `UserContext.USERNAME`.

Simple, right?

Comment: Can you explain a little more about implementing a factory?